# Google Sheets - Subtract column 2 from column 1 if name matches and 2nd column is blank

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a formula that will add up the number of times John appears in Column A if Column B is blank.

=Countif(A1:A5, "John", (B1:B5, ""))

Sample data:

A          B

John
John
Tom       345
Brad      345
John      345

Answer (score 0):

Try "countifs" instead:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"John",B1:B5,"")
```

Comment: Wow, so close. Thanks!